# Does Tor hide my mac address as well as my IP address?

Tags: anonymity, browsers

Does Tor hide my mac address as well as my IP address?
And what about if I have another browser such as IE or Firefox open at the same time as Tor,  but not in Tor?

Answer (score 4):

In general when you visit a website the website won't be able to see your MAC address, even when *not* using Tor.

Only the hop directly after you is able to see your MAC, and chances are there's 10+ hops between you and a given web server.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. In the case of another browser open as well as Tor, does that compromise Tor?

Comment: It shouldn't compromise your Tor session, no.
Your other browser of course won't be secure though.